# Check whether a given map is a complex chart

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

An example of complex chart on $\mathbb{R^2}$ is given by $f_U$ defined below:

$$
f_U(x,y)=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+i\frac{y}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$

where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. How do I show that $f_U$ is an homeomorphism? It is clearly continuous. An inverse could be $f^{-1}(z)=(\frac{Re(z)}{1-|z|},\frac{Im(z)}{1-|z|})$. However, the last one is not in general continuous. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|f_U(x,y)| <1$, hence $f^{-1}(z)=(\frac{Re(z)}{1-|z|},\frac{Im(z)}{1-|z|})$ is only defined for $z \in \mathbb C$ with $|z|<1$.

Conclusion: $f^{-1}$ is continuous.